# My several Windows XP programs disappeared

Tags: windows

I have several programs disappeared from my computer ( Win XP ). They are :

- Notepad
- System Restore
- Windows Media Player ( It disappear. I can't find it everywhere but when I opened a song, the song is played with WMP. Weird ! )
- In Start Menu -> Accessories --> Entertaiment, It is empty. But there is no missing audio or sound.
- There is still other programs disappear. The conclusion is I found that several programs disappeared or lost from my start menu ( especially Accessories ).

Why ?

My command prompt can't recognized **attrib /?**. Why ?

My disk defragmenter is still there. But, when I opened, It appeared a windows " Open with.." . I can't do anything then.

Any solution for my those problems ? I am very stressed with them

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downloading and running a utility called unhide, or they may be found in a folder named smtmp inside:

C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Local Settings\Temp

These will be there unless you have removed temp files / folders
There could be multiple numbered folders wich will be numbered 1,2 and 4.

All you have to do then is look in the 1 folder for a folder named "Programs" and copy/paste this to:
 C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu 
wich would probably already have that folder but it is safe to overwrite since windows will replace the subfolders as well.

Inside folder 2 you should select all of the quick launch items and paste them into:
 C:\Documents and Settings\Your User Name\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch.

Inside the folder 4 there are desktop items that should be copied to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop

If you can't find the smtp folder you might want to check C:\Windows\Temp, copy them into C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Local Settings\Temp